# How present UIMenuController and UIAlertController at the same time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller, uimenucontroller

I'm trying next way:

```
Message *message = self.messagesArray[indexPath.row];
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:LocalizedString(@"FirstAction")
                                                                         message:@""
                                                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIAlertAction *editMessage = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:LocalizedString(@"SecondAction") style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
}];
[alertController addAction:editMessage];
UIAlertAction *forwardMessage = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:LocalizedString(@"ThirdAction") style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
}];
[alertController addAction:forwardMessage];
UIAlertAction *deleteMessage = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:LocalizedString(@"DeleteMessage") style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
}];
[alertController addAction:deleteMessage];
[self setSourceViewForAlertController:alertController];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
[self createMenuForMessage:message];
[[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
```

So, my aim is to present alertcontroller for UICollectionViewCell and UIMenuController at the same time.

Like this:
[image]

Comment: show your requirement

Comment: plz elobrate....

Comment: You need show both things at the same time??? why you want to do this?

Comment: @ReinierMelian Just for more options for user. If it's not possible, I will search for other UX decision.

Comment: maybe its possible but I think its not the best approach, I suggest you only the actionSheet or the menu, both things will make the user confused about this

Comment: This would not work by default. The action sheet will get dismissed if you click outside the white area.

Comment: @ReinierMelian this variant used by Telegram.

Comment: @Viktorianec I will check that then

Comment: @Viktorianec what is your issue actually, I can show the actionSheet and the menu but the menu can be touched until the actionSheet is dismissed

Comment: @ReinierMelian when I show UIAlertController, menu will be dismissed... But I need them both. Could you show how you present them?

Comment: @Viktorianec this works, the menu can be touched without any problem, so maybe its your needed solution, let me know

Comment: @Viktorianec did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is related to where are you showing your `UIMenuController` you have to take in account that `UIView` must have implemented the `canBecomeFirstResponder` method returning `YES`

```
- (IBAction)action:(id)sender {
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@""
                                                                             message:@""
                                                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    UIAlertAction *editMessage = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    }];
    [alertController addAction:editMessage];
    UIAlertAction *forwardMessage = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Move" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    }];
    [alertController addAction:forwardMessage];
    UIAlertAction *deleteMessage = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Delete" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    }];
    [alertController addAction:deleteMessage];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
    [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setTargetRect:self.view.bounds inView:self.view];
    [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setArrowDirection:UIMenuControllerArrowDefault];
    [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuItems:@[[[UIMenuItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"test" action:@selector(didReceiveMemoryWarning)]]];
    [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
}

-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder{
    return true;
}
```

[image]

Comment: canBecomeFirstResponder give me a crash:
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view controller:<UICompatibilityInputViewController: 0x111bbfaa0> should have parent view controller:<VCDialog"

Comment: @Viktorianec can you give me some details of your setup?

Comment: I use custom inputView, so I think that it cause that crash. And that's reason why I couldn't show with the way you provided. But I think that you give a right answer... Anyway it's not a solution for my situation.

Comment: @Viktorianec but your custom input view is a UIView subclass?

Comment: I use UIPageController with Stickers

Comment: @Viktorianec you need to take in account that the view where you are telling the MenuController will be showed is where you need to implement 'canBecomeFirstResponder'

Comment: I know it. I have a parent view controller, in which I use stickers as inputview. Also I present UIAlertController and UIMenu for index path. And it's reason for crash (:

Comment: This is a test proyect or a real one? @Viktorianec

Comment: Real in production. I couldn't provide more code. But thank you very much for your help yesterday and today. It's really difficult case to understand.

Comment: Ok, I understand you, so good luck then, best regards @Viktorianec